# JPA persistence.xml not dropping all schema tables

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly

When I deploy to my Wildfly I expect that all my database tables will be dropped and created again. But some old tables (old Java Entities) are still present in my database.

This is my `persistence.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="gestalPU">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source"
                value="metadata" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source"
                value="metadata" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
                value="insert.sql" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-database-schemas" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>    
</persistence>
```

Comment: and are the "old tables" for some current JPA entities?

Answer (score 1):

`drop-and-create` only drops tables related to current entities, it does not purge the entire schema.

So for example if you renamed an entity, the table corresponding to the old entity name will remain in the database.

Comment: And how can I automate the dropping of all tables before creating the new ones ?